# UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https

Tags: apex, webservices

Critical Updates there is no Update Name   (Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" in that list) 
[image]
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Critical Updates --(Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections is not there my sandbox how to enable ...urgent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Critical Updates page, it is possible to activate and deactivate Critical Updates, but only up until the auto-activation date. See [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cruc_overview.htm):

> To ensure a smooth transition, each update has an opt-in period during which you can manually activate and deactivate the update an unlimited number of times to evaluate its impact on your organization and modify affected customizations as necessary. The opt-in period ends on the auto-activation date, at which time Salesforce permanently activates the update.

For sandboxes, the auto-activation date for TLS 1.0 Disablement was June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC). See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207&language=en_US):

> After this date and time, all sandbox orgs -- whether existing, refreshed, or new -- will have TLS 1.0 automatically disabled and will require TLS 1.1 or later in HTTPS connections to or from the sandbox org. The "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" CRUC setting will not be available.

Comment: Hi Martin Critical Updates --(Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections is not there my sandbox how to enable

Comment: @RameshM I hate to say it, but I don't think there's a workaround for this one.