# Salesforce Sandbox API, using .Net web service - Please use TLS 1.1 or higher

Tags: soap-api, soap, .net, tls

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to the Salesforce sandbox API via a .NET SOAP webservice, when using IIS 10. None of the other similar questions I've found on Salesforce Stack Exchange provide a solution that works for me.

```
UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.
```

I've checked in the Salesforce sandbox under 'critical updates', but there is no update related to TLS 1.1 that I could disable.

I've also tried editing my registry using the following guides (one of these is for IIS 7.5 but I tried it anyway as nothing else is working)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/187498/how-to-disable-pct-1.0,-ssl-2.0,-ssl-3.0,-or-tls-1.0-in-internet-information-services

https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/#

What do I need to do to get this to work? the error states that the problem is with the client, so it must be something I need to change at my service end.

Comment: You can't enable support for TLS 1.0 any more. You need to update your code to use a more modern handshake protocol. More users have experience with how that works for .NET on [so], so you may have better luck there.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this question is different. I've edited the title to clarify, and I found my solution, which turned out to be a code change in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I found that for my .NET project, a code change was required to ensure that the web service doesn't try to use TLS 1.0. I added this line before attempting to programatically log in:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

I also discovered that the reason there's nothing in the Salesforce sandbox under 'critical updates' is because the auto-activation date for this update has now passed:

[UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133458/unsupported-client-tls-1-0-has-been-disabled-in-this-organization-please-use-t)